# How to get the SOAP request from an ActiveMQ queue and implement it in the webservice

Tags: mule, activemq-classic, mule-studio

I have a requirement in Mule in which I need to expose a SOAP web service ..
Now I am implementing it in 2 flows :-

```
<flow name="ServiceFlow" doc:name="ServiceFlow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP" />
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData" doc:name="SOAP" />
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="NewQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>


<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2" >
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://tcp:NewQueue" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl" >
<method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="retrieveDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="insertDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="updateDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="deleteDataOperation"/>
</method-entry-point-resolver>
</component>
<logger level="INFO" message="payload :-#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

In the first flow (ServiceFlow) I am trying to send the SOAP request in an ActiveMQ queue and in second flow (Flow2) ..I am trying to consume the request in **MainDataImpl** class .. But I am getting an exception while consuming the request :-

```
Exception stack is:
1. "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49419-1407595657591-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage (org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler:81 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jms/redelivery/MessageRedeliveredException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException: "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49419-1407595657591-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler.handleRedelivery(JmsXRedeliveryHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$JmsWorker.preProcessMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:512)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1$1.process(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:117)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Now I want to know how can I resolve the issue as I guess **MainDataImpl** is expecting the message as object type .. but there is no way to convert the String message into Object ... Any solution for the above issue ??? Please Help

**UPDATE AFTER ADDING OBJECT TO XML:-**

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>

<flow name="ServiceFlow" doc:name="ServiceFlow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP" />
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData" doc:name="SOAP" />
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>

<!-- <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="Flow1-WT-Main" doc:name="VM"/> -->

   <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="NewQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>


<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2" >
<!-- <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="Flow1-WT-Main" doc:name="VM"/> -->

<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://tcp:NewQueue" doc:name="JMS" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <logger message="Payload :-#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </async>
<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl" >
<method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="retrieveDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="insertDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="updateDataOperation"/>
        <include-entry-point method="deleteDataOperation"/>
</method-entry-point-resolver>

</component>

<logger level="INFO" message="ccccccc :-#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Now the exception is :-

```
INFO  2014-08-09 21:10:33,426 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ccccccc :-com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.DataResponse@1ca5a88a
INFO  2014-08-09 21:10:33,426 [[Dummysimpleclientwebservice].Flow2.1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Payload :-com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.DataRequest@3fdc0ab7
ERROR 2014-08-09 21:10:33,433 [ActiveMQ Session Task-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DataResponse (javax.jms.JMSException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DataResponse(JMS Code: null) (javax.jms.JMSException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils:144 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/jms/JMSException.html)
2. Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DataResponse (javax.jms.JMSException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer:79 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.jms.JMSException: Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was DataResponse
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils.toMessage(JmsMessageUtils.java:144)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer.transformToMessage(AbstractJmsTransformer.java:66)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage.transformMessage(ObjectToJMSMessage.java:54)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2014-08-09 21:10:34,488 [ActiveMQ Session Task-2] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49768-1407598818233-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49768-1407598818233-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage (org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException)
  org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler:81 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/jms/redelivery/MessageRedeliveredException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.MessageRedeliveredException: "Message with id "ID:ANIRBAN-PC-49768-1407598818233-1:1:6:1:1" has been redelivered 1 times on endpoint "jms://tcp:NewQueue", which exceeds the maxRedelivery setting of 0 on the connector "Active_MQ". Message payload is of type: ActiveMQTextMessage
    at org.mule.transport.jms.redelivery.JmsXRedeliveryHandler.handleRedelivery(JmsXRedeliveryHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver$JmsWorker.preProcessMessage(MultiConsumerJmsMessageReceiver.java:512)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractReceiverWorker$1$1.process(AbstractReceiverWorker.java:117)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: I think you are showing the wrong error: the redelivery exceeded error is a probably the consequence of the incapacity for `Flow2` to consume the JMS message successfully. Can you show the actual error?

Comment: Hi David .. Pls check updated error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed it, the problem is that you serialize the inbound message object to a String with `object-to-string-transformer` and, via a JMS queue, try to feed it to the `MainDataImpl` object, which takes objects as input parameters for its different operations.

The solution is to simply serialize the inbound object to XML, send it via JMS then deserialize it back to an object.

For this replace the `object-to-string-transformer` with an `object-to-xml-transformer` and add a `xml-to-object-transformer` right after the `jms:inbound-endpoint`.

**EDIT**
I didn't realize you're using `NewQueue` in `request-response` fashion, because you actually inconsistently declare it. On the `jms:outbound-endpoint` you do not provide an `exchange-pattern` which makes it `one-way` by default ; while on the `jms:inbound-endpoint` your set the `exchange-pattern` to `request-response`, which triggers the execution of the response phase of `Flow2`.

So: **be consistent**, use the same `exchange-pattern` on both JMS endpoints or, even better, declare a global JMS endpoint with the right `exchange-pattern` and ref-it from the jms:inbound and outbound endpoints.

If you decide to stay with `request-response`, then you need to do the same for the response, ie. serialize the result of calling `MainDataImpl` (a `DataResponse` object) back to XML and in `ServiceFlow` deserialize it back to object.

Comment: Hi David .. I have tried the same you suggested .. But still facing exception .. pls find the modification in the question ... I have updated with UPDATE AFTER ADDING OBJECT TO XML tag ..

Answer (score 0):

So, the working solution is (as per David's suggestion)
1. Need to add `<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>` before JMS outbound and `<mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>` after JMS inbound
2. Need to use the same `exchange-pattern` on both JMS endpoints